# Plesk php api exception thrown

Tags: php, api, plesk

I get the following error when I sample api code for plesk.

exception 'ApiRequestException' with message 'Could not resolve host: https:; No data record of requested type' in C:\wamp\www\plesk.php:169 Stack trace: #0 C:\wamp\www\plesk.php(255): sendRequest(Resource id #2, '

here is the sample code I am using.
http://download1.parallels.com/Plesk/Plesk8.1/Doc/plesk-8.1-api-rpc-guide/33181.htm

Looking forward for some help.

Regards,

BG

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the host you sent request is not resolved.  Make sure the host is reachable from  the machine that you run the script (simply use ping utility for that). if the hostname has no a true domain name, please edit C:\Windows\System32\drivers\hosts to link IP address with the used domain name.